# About GoogleMaps SDK for iOS licenses

Tags: ios, licensing, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm developing an app for ios and using GoogleMaps SDK for displaying my maps, but my app is for a company that documents all used libraries, and I have to report license info about GoogleMaps SDK. I'm googling about it since yesterday and did not find anything usefull in my case. My question is:

1- What kind of license is it? BSD? GPL?

2- Whats the license name? I've seen an "Except as otherwise noted, the content of this page is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License, and code samples are licensed under the Apache 2.0 License. For details, see our Site Policies." on the bottom of all document pages, but I'm not sure if the CC License is about the written contents or about the library itself...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an open source license like GPL or BSD, it's a [proprietary software license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license#Proprietary_software_licenses), ie something that Google have come up with specific to that software.

The header files say something like this:

```
//
//  GoogleMaps.h
//  Google Maps SDK for iOS
//
//  Copyright 2012 Google Inc.
//
//  Usage of this SDK is subject to the Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of
//  Service: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms
//
```

So you can look at https://developers.google.com/maps/terms to see the full terms of the license.

However, the SDK is built upon a number of open source components. You can retrieve details of all of these licenses by calling `[GMSServices openSourceLicenseInfo]`, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_services). You are meant to display this license info within your app.